# How to input the equation with power of number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript and here is my struggle with my homework, hope you guys can help me with this one:

```
futureInvestment = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^numberOfYears*12
```

How to implement this equation? Thanks

Comment: Is it java or javascript?

Comment: Java =/= Javascript

Comment: It's a Javascript, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Math.pow()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

To calculate `x^y` say `Math.pow(x, y)`. For example:

```
Math.pow(2, 4)  // returns 16
Math.pow(13, 3) // returns 2197
```

*(Since you've mentioned that you're working on homework I'll give you a chance to figure out for yourself how to apply `Math.pow()` to your particular calculation rather than just giving you the final answer immediately.)*

Comment: That's another problem, using other code that you haven't shown in your question. I'd suggest posting another question with your latest (full but relevant) code for help with that, because the question you've actually asked here has been answered.